# Dynamic item template for paginator directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a paginator directive that lists items in an array:

```
    .directive('paginator', function() {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: 
           '<div ng-repeat="item in items">' +
               '<?>' + 
           '</div>' + 

            '<div>' + 
                '<button ng-click="goPrevious()">Previous</button>' +
                '<div>{{ currentPage }}/{{ numberOfPages() }}</div>' + 
                '<button ng-click="goNext()">Next</button>' +
            '</div>', 
        scope: {
          items: '=',
          itemsPerPage: '='
    },
        ...
    }
```

Where "`<?>`" should be the item template. What I want is generalize it and pass any template that i need. Someone have any idea how I could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for ngTransclude (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

Check this example out:

```
<script>
  function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    $scope.text = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...';
  }

  angular.module('transclude', [])
   .directive('pane', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { title:'@' },
        template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                    '<div style="background-color: gray">{{title}}</div>' +
                    '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                  '</div>'
      };
  });
</script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input ng-model="title"><br>
  <textarea ng-model="text"></textarea> <br/>
  <pane title="{{title}}">{{text}}</pane>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is where transclusion comes into play.

```
{
   restrict:'E'
   transclude:true,
   template: "<div id='outer'>" +
               "<h1>I'm a widget</h1>" +
               "<div ng-transclude>" +
               "<!-- template goes here -->" +
               "</div>" +
             "</div>"
}
```

Which you would then use like this in your markup:

```
<my-widget>
   <div>I'm just a plain old div</div>
   <span>and I'm just a span</span>
</my-widget>
```